# Symbol 'EDT_OGLES2' could not be resolved

Tags: android, android-ndk, irrlicht

Iam trying to port irrlicht helloworld programme to android.. but when i set my device type to OGLES2 it give me error Symbol 'EDT_OGLES2' could not be resolved
Here is screenshot of my cpp file[image]

Any idea what iam doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through documentation of irrlicht, i found that i have to add and enum variable EDT_OGLES1 or EDT_OGLES2 in EDriverTypes.h. Finally compiled and everything is working fine.